# Unable to use subject and formatting in gmail smtp php

Tags: php, email, curl, smtp

I managed to send a gmail mail using smtp curl but for some reasons i can't find where should i add the subject part of the mail and im also trying to figure out how to use formatting.

For the subject i tried to add it in the fwrite but without success.

For formatting i tried using strong,h1,h2.. inside the $message without success.

If you have any ideeas let me know.

This is my code:

```
$subject = 'something'
$message = 'body';
$emailFile = fopen("php://temp", 'w+');
fwrite($emailFile, "$message");
rewind($emailFile);
$proxy     = $data;
$fstat     = fstat($emailFile);
$size      = $fstat['size'];
$ch        = curl_init('smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, "<" . 'test@gmail.com' . ">");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, array(
    "<" . 'receiver@gmail.com' . ">"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERNAME, 'test@gmail.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, 'password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_ALL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $emailFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $size);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
fclose($emailFile);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Idea: download a library designed to send mail. Don't try doing this by hand.

Comment: I tried libs but they don't work well with proxies, curl worked best with proxies for me.

Comment: Good luck with that then. [RFC 5322 will get you started](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322); the subject is just a header, and if you want to use HTML you'll need to create a MIME multipart message with appropriate encoding and separators.